# HTML/CSS: how can I make the checkboxes grow when zooming in and shrink when zooming out?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have this simple code for testing:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    ul{
        float:left;
        margin:0;
        list-style:none;
        padding:0;
      }
</style>
    </head>
<body>
    <ul>
       <li><input type="checkbox" id="c1" class="checkBox">a</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="c2" class="checkBox"/>b</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="c3" class="checkBox"/>c</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="c4" class="checkBox"/>d</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="c5" class="checkBox"/>e</li>
           <li><input type="checkbox" id="c6" class="checkBox" />f</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="c7" class="checkBox"/>g</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="c8" class="checkBox"/>h</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="c9" class="checkBox"/>i</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the result:

[image]

but if I zoom out the text gets smaller but the checkboxes remain the same

[image]

and if I zoom in the text gets bigger but the checkboxes remain the same

[image]

is it possible to make it so that the checkboxes would change their size as well? for example proportionally to the size of their label?
thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot do that and btw you've tagged your question totally wrongly

Comment: thanks for noticing, they were tags I used for a question I wanted to ask but eventually never did.

Comment: Yes, you cannot resize checkboxes. You cannot style checkboxes. They are rendered by the OS.
I know for one solution - use JS to hide checkboxes, then make a new html elements (span, div) instead and simulate the behaviour. Then you can style this new element with Media Queries.

Comment: @marinbgd it's not necessarily use JS. it can be implemented with CSS only in all post IE8 browsers.

Comment: How? I even cannot change color or background of checkbox when use CSS directly on the checkbox. I tried with Chrome v23. Write an answer.

Comment: @marinbgd I don't think it's a proper answer to the question, so here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UVLLN/8/) for your question.

Comment: Not bad. I'll try to use this solution somewhere and see if it is good. Nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cW4Vf/)

Use CSS3 to zoom the list as well as the browser rendered checkboxes!

```css
.extraLarge ul {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.50);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.50);
  -o-transform: scale(1.50);
  transform: scale(1.50);
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I didn't even know that it's possible. Good stuff :)

Comment: Strictly speaking this alone does not solve the problem described by the OP: as you change browser zoom, the checkboxes will still be either too small or too large except at the default zoom.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with CSS3 a by using the :checked selector. What this does is use a styled input with a background image. So when you zoom in/out, it will re-size, along with the text. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in IE9 and under.

CSS:

```
.theCheckbox input {
    display: none;
}

.theCheckbox span {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    background: url("link_to_image");
}

.theCheckbox input:checked + span {
    background: url("link_to_checked_image");
}
```

HTML:

```
<label for="test">Label for checkbox</label>
<label class="theCheckbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="test"/>
    <span></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own checkbox control, so that you would not rely on the native OS implementation. When you create it using common html elements then browser zoom will work smoothly.

There are plenty of existing plugins for libraries (like jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has a **"text-only"** zoom feature, unlike Chrome that lacks this feature.

To make **everything** zoom in Firefox, **remove** the checkmark and Reset the zoom level.

[image]

For Chrome browser, look into Zoom plugins that have this feature.